# Clear Query Table Result in OAF on page refresh

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps

I have an requirement to clear the table search result on page referesh.
I have added the below code in processRequest of my Controller but it is not working.

[image]

My Page Structure looks like this:

[image]

**Note**

I have also tried to clear cache of tableBean but that is also not working.
Is there any other method to clear search results.

Do let me know.

Thanks

Comment: i have the same requirement. were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @MigsIsip No, i cleared by using VO clear.